# The mirrored half can still be manipulated

Tags: mirror

When I mirror an object, the mirrored half still has vertices and doesn't move with the other half.
[image]

That's what it's supposed to be like, right?

Welp, this is what happens when I try it.
[image]

What should I do?
Seriously, this is actually really important to me.

Answer (score 3):

looks like you applied the modifier. Now your mesh is one. Select all the verts on the left side, delete them, than add the mirror modifier again

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you applied the mirror modifier. When not applied, it will always mirror the left part of your mesh, so leave it this way. Only when you need to change your mesh in a non-mirror way, apply the modifier.